# need to select multiple image with dropdown on angular2

Tags: angular

**html**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3 materialpo">
                                    <label>{{'MATERIAL' | translate}} 
                                    </label><span class="errorMsg">* 
                                    </span> <br />

<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="selctedOrderLine.material"

(completeMethod)="searchMaterial($event)" field="displayValue" 
[minLength]="1"
                                        formControlName="material" 
[size]="30" [style]="{'width':'318px'}"
                                        placeholder="Enter Material" 
(ngModelChange)="materialMsg=''" [dropdown]="true"

(onDropdownClick)="handleMaterialDropdownClick($event)"

[disabled]="disableMaterialField">

</p-autoComplete>

</div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center"
*ngFor="let image of imagess; let i=index">

  <input type="checkbox" 
    [(ngModel)]="val" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event.target.checked)" name="team" 
    [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
     <img [src]="image" />
   </div>
```

**ts**

```
onChange(isCheck:any){
    if(isCheck){
        this.changeborder=true;
    }else{
        this.changeborder=false;
    }
}
```

I have just added a single drowpdown and some image displayed with checkbox. 
I want to make like select multiple images with dropdown.

Please give some idea  about multiple images with dropdown in angular.

Comment: create key like `changeborder` in `imagess` Array change key value on change event.

Comment: but image part is also not working, the problem is when i select one image it selects all and also it does not affect on dropdown @Abhishek

Comment: can you create stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gnotnt here is the sample and i want to select multiple image that reflects with dropdown, please check once. thank u @Abhishek

Comment: look at this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-huyhqg i think can help you

Comment: yes it is but i need to select the dropdown value also if click on image or select image if click on dropdown value.(looks like the cc value's image is 1st one , yelo value's image is 2st one) @Abhishek thank u.

Answer (score 0):

```
step 1 : set checked key along with image.

   ex. this.imagess = [{ 'checked': false , 'image' :'abc1.jpeg'} , { 'checked': false , 'imageUrl' :'abc2.jpeg'}];

bind same checked property in templeate.

step 2

<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-3 materialpo">
                                    <label>{{'MATERIAL' | translate}} 
                                    </label><span class="errorMsg">* 
                                    </span> <br />

<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="selctedOrderLine.material"

(completeMethod)="searchMaterial($event)" field="displayValue" 
[minLength]="1"
                                        formControlName="material" 
[size]="30" [style]="{'width':'318px'}"
                                        placeholder="Enter Material" 
(ngModelChange)="materialMsg=''" [dropdown]="true"

(onDropdownClick)="handleMaterialDropdownClick($event)"

[disabled]="disableMaterialField">

</p-autoComplete>

</div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center"
*ngFor="let image of imagess; let i=index">

  <input type="checkbox" 
    [(ngModel)]="image['checked']" name="team{{i}}"/>
     <img [src]="image['imageUrl']" />
   </div>
```

Comment: thank you @Manishkumar Bhavnani but if the images value coming from backend then will i make the key also

Comment: when response come you have manipulate same array of object to bind with ngmodel.